# Probability of randomly choosing a company that will get sued

Tags: probability, statistics

I am attempting to calculate the probability that a company chosen at random from a list of 4,000 each day will get sued in the next 30 days.

I know that the chance of a company getting sued in a given year is 8.5%, or 0.023% each day (8.5% ÷ 365 days).

What I'm struggling to work out is, if I choose 5 companies at random each day from a list of 4,000, what the probability of those companies getting sued in the next 30 days would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that the probability that any company is sued on a particular day is fixed at $0.00023$. (*Its unclear if this is a reasonable assumption. If a company was sued yesterday, is it still "getting sued" today?*) To answer the question, we can use the fact that the probability of an event and its complement sum to one.

$$P(A) + P(A^c) = 1$$

The probability of not getting sued on a particular day is

\begin{align}
P(Not\ Sued\ Today) &= 1 - P(Sued\ Today)\\
&= 1 - 0.00023\\
&= 0.99977
\end{align}

and the probability of being sued in the next thirty days is one minus the probability of not being sued, thirty days in a row:

\begin{align}
P(Sued\ in\ Next\ 30\ days) &= 1 - P(Not\ Sued\ in\ Next\ 30\ days)\\
&= 1 - .99977^{30}\\
&\approx .00688
\end{align}

The number of companies we *could* choose from is irrelevant. The probability of a lawsuit within $30$ days in a group of five random companies is one minus the probability of no lawsuits within $30$ days in a group of five random companies.

\begin{align}
P(a\ Suit\ Within\ 5\ CompanyMonths) &= 1 - P(No\ Suit\ Within\ 5\ CompanyMonths)\\
&= 1 - ({.99977^{30}})^{5}\\
&\approx 0.034
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this. It makes perfect sense (noting your assumption at the top). Let's now say that the 5 random choices were only made on working days. Would that have any effect on the probability?

Comment: This works if you select only five companies on day 1, but once you choose five more companies the next day, the probability changes (the first ones getting sued in the next 29 days plus the new ones). Also it might be possible to choose an already chosen company.